# The desired result is required by the function

Tags: python, string, function, class, selenium-webdriver

**My Code:**

```
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
import pandas as pd
@dataclass
class Business(object):

    Job_Trade: str = None

    def __repr__(self):
        attrs = [f'{attr}={getattr(self, attr)!r}' for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({", ".join(attrs)})'
    pass
def add_variable(class_name, variable_name, valuee):
     setattr(class_name, variable_name, valuee) # Default Value is `None`

@dataclass
class BusinessList:
    business_list : list[Business] = field(default_factory=list)

business = Business()
business.Job_Trade = 'Licensed Customer Service Representative'
add_variable(business, 'Company', 'Global Payments')

business_list = BusinessList()
business_list.business_list.append(business)
df = pd.DataFrame(business_list.business_list)
print(df)
```

**Result:**

```
                                  Job_Trade
0  Licensed Customer Service Representative
```

**Required:**
I Need This, When I Print.

```
print(df)
```

**Required Result**

```
                                  Job_Trade          Company
0  Licensed Customer Service Representative  Global Payments
```

Thanks for your replies it's really useful. And I have updated my problem, please let me know

Please help to solve the puzzle.

Comment: If you want Company to be listed in the representation, then you have to add it to the data class.  Right now, all you have is `Job_Trade`.  Just add another line to `Business` that looks just like that with `Company`.  `dataclass` uses an internal list to track the fields it knows about.  You're bypassing that list.

Answer (score 1):

(This solution was posted before the question was edited with the requirement of having a function declarations)

You can try the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Business:
    Job_Trade: str = None
    Company: str = None

    def __repr__(self):
        attrs = [f'{key}={getattr(self, key)!r}' for key in self.__annotations__.keys()]
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({", ".join(attrs)})'

business = Business()
business.Job_Trade = 'Licensed Customer Service Representative'
business.Company = 'Global Payments'


print(business.Company)
print(business.Job_Trade)
print(business)
```

Output is as follows:

```
Global Payments
Licensed Customer Service Representative
Business(Job_Trade='Licensed Customer Service Representative', Company='Global Payments')
```

Comment: ```Company: str = None
```
This way I have to insert a lot of entries in different parts of the code, and it causes error many times.
Do not use it as a manual declaration variable of 'class Business:'.
I need a function to declare it.
@AlefiyaAbbas

Comment: Thanks for your reply it's really useful.
And I have updated my problem, please let me know user name: @AlefiyaAbbas

Comment: Do you still don't want to use `Company: str = None ` ?

Comment: Company: str = None
if I use it 30+ times and change its name (Company:) from time to time and I don't want to make too many changes to different parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following without having to declare Company variable

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Business:
    Job_Trade: str = None

    def __repr__(self):
        attrs = [f'{attr}={getattr(self, attr)!r}' for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({", ".join(attrs)})'

def add_variable(class_name, variable_name, valuee):
     setattr(class_name, variable_name, valuee) # Default Value is `None`

business = Business()

business.Job_Trade = 'Licensed Customer Service Representative'

add_variable(business, 'Company', 'Global Payments')

print(business.Company)
print(business.Job_Trade)
print(business)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the 3 answers you've posted so far over the last few hours, all are either mostly code with no explanation, appear likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), or both. A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. For answers where you have not used AI, keep in mind that providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* your code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: no this Answer posted by my self ..
my question and their comments are self explanatory. that why.